# Can someone explain the special std::function template parameter list syntax(this strange Type(Types...))?

Tags: c++, templates

Can someone explain the special `std::function` syntax(this strange `Type(Types...)`)?What are this parentheses? I know that what is inside means argument list of function.

I just wonder what this syntax means.

```
//What am I doing? Can someone explain?

std::vector<int>      a; // 
std::vector<int(int)> b; // it counts as a type

//or
std::tuple<double, double> t1{0.0, 0.0}; // okey
std::tuple<double(double)> t2{0.0, 0.0}; // not okey, not the same as above(please explain what happens)
```

Comment: Function return type and parameter types, what's unclear about that please??

Comment: I wasn't complete question. I know how to use std::function.

Comment: What does you now posted example code have to do with `std::function`?

Comment: It does seem obvious after you point it out, @πάνταῥεῖ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Type(Types...)` is **not** a "special syntax". The reason `std::function` takes `R(Args...)` is that it specializes for the function type `R(Args...)`. Here is its declaration from the standard:

```
template<class> class function; // undefined
template<class R, class... ArgTypes> class function<R(ArgTypes...)>;
```

The important thing to understand is that the `R(ArgTypes...)` syntax specifies a function type. If you declare a function such as `int foo(int arg)`, the type of `foo` is `int(int)`.

You can create your own structures that accept arguments in this way like so:

```
template <class>
struct X;

template <class R, class ...Args>
struct X<R(Args...)> {
   typedef R result_type;
   // ... whatever
};
```

The reason why you can't use `int(int)` with `std::vector` or `std::tuple` is because of their declarations:

```
template<class T, class Allocator = allocator<T>> class vector;
template<class... Types> class tuple;
```

When you do `std::vector<int(int)>`, you substitute `T` for `int(int)`, which won't work because the construction of `std::allocator<int(int)>` will fail (you can't allocate function types).

When you do `std::tuple<int(int)>`, you are passing `int(int)` as the first type in the parameter pack `Types`, which won't work either because you cannot have function types be a data member.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have a function type as a template parameter for `std::vector` (or `std::tuple`), but you can have a function **pointer** type in this role. For example,

```
int foo(int x) { return 2 * x; }
int bar(int x) { return 3 * x; }

std::vector<int(*)(int)> v{&foo, &bar}; // & is optional here
std::cout << v[0](5); // Calls foo(5), outputs 10
std::cout << v[1](5); // Calls bar(5), outputs 15
```

Answer (score 0):

When you declare a function in C++ you use virtually exactly the same syntax

```
return_type function_name(parameter_type1, parameter_type2 /* and so on */)
```

I hope you don't find it strange. In function declaration syntax parentheses surround the parameter list.

Now, if you remove the `function_name` from this syntax you'll be left with just function type itself, "extracted" from that declaration

```
return_type (parameter_type1, parameter_type2)
```

That's just how you describe an ordinary function type in C++. Actually, it is inherited directly from C. Nothing new, strange or unusual about it.

For another example, when you are declaring

```
int a[10];
```

you are actually declaring name `a` as having type `int [10]`. In the very same fashion, when you are declaring

```
double a(double);
```

you are actually declaring name `a` as having type `double (double)`.

And you can't use function type as container element type or tuple element type. Function type is not *object* type. And these contexts actually require object types.

But you can (and you have) to use it as template argument for `std::function`.